# How to calculate the sum of two squares of integer-order Bessel function, multiplied by the cosine of the sum of the orders of the Bessel functions?

Tags: special-functions, summation

How to calculate the sum of two squares of integer-order Bessel function, multiplied by the cosine of the sum of the orders of the Bessel functions:

\begin{align}
\sum _{p=-\infty }^{+\infty } \sum _{q=-\infty }^{+\infty } J_p(\text{a1}){}^2
   J_q(\text{a2}){}^2 \cos \big((p+q) b+c\big)
\end{align}

I tried this:

```
Sum[
  BesselJ[ p, a1 ]^2 × BesselJ[ q, a2 ]^2 × Cos[ (p + q) b + c ],
  { p, -∞, +∞ },
  { q, -∞, +∞ }
]
```

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a symbolic answer here.  Note that you can rewrite this as a (sum of) the products of two 1D sums.  However, Mathematica has no symbolic result for even much simpler sums, such as `Sum[BesselJ[p, a1]^2, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}]` which is a special case of your expression.